# Canon EOS 1V HS doesn't fire Canon EX430 ii or PocketWizard

Tags: troubleshooting, pocket-wizard, canon-1v, canon-ex430ii

I've Canon EOS 1V HS, the camera works perfect, only problem is it doesn't fire Canon EX430 ii when it's set in manual mode, it does fire it if I set the flash as TTL. Also it doesn't fire my pocket wizard when I have it on the hot shoe, anyone knows what's the problem?

Comment: I have an EOS-1V HS and a 430EX II and the camera triggers the flash in manual mode just as my other bodies does. I don't own any Pocket Wizards however. Can't the camera trigger the flash through the Pocket Wizards or is it just the manual mode that won't work? Have you been using the EOS-1V with other flashguns?

Comment: @Hugo the camera doesn't fire with the flash only in Manual mode, it does fire it using TTL mode. It doesn't fire the Pocket Wizard wirelessly. I can definitely try to fire the pocket wizard using PC connection

Comment: Ok, so the flash won't fire even in TTL mode using the Pocket Wizards? Yes try firing the flash through the PC connection as well as make sure that it isn't he flash that is the problem.

Comment: @Hugo i'll try that but it's not the flash problem cause it works fine in manual on my Canon T3i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after lot of experimenting and trying and reading with no obvious reason why the flash in manual mode and pocket wizard don't work (pocket wizard works with pc connection), I tried to use hotshoe adapter that I had long time ago (see pictures) and everything now works fine! I've no explanation if anyone understands why please jump in.

[image]
[image]